# Probability of rolling above a certain number across multiple 20 sided dice.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

What is the probability of rolling a $15$ or higher on any of a set of $20$-sided dice.

For example. If I have $3$ $20$-sided dice, what are the odds that if I roll all three of them the result on at least one of them will be a $15$ or higher.

Comment: Your thoughts? What did you try?

Comment: I have been all over the board with this. But it's been so many years since I looked into probability I'm not sure where to start. Based on a few different places I mainly thought of
`1-(14/20)^n`
But this was based on the formula for rolling a 6 on n dice.
"`P(a 6 in two rolls) = 1-(5/6)^2`
similarly for six rolls it will be `1-(5/6)^6`"

Comment: @MiuKujo What you wrote in your comment (efforts and eventually despair) should be part of your question.

Comment: [Odds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odds) and [probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability) do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, consider for $1$ dice. Let $X$ be the random variable that refers to the value of the dice.
\begin{align}
P(X\geq 15) 
&= P(X = 15 \lor X = 16 \lor X = 17 \lor X = 18 \lor X = 19 \lor X = 20) 
\\&= P(X=15) + P(X=16) +
P(X=17) +
P(X=18) +
P(X=19) +
P(X=20) 
\\&= 6\times\frac{1}{20} 
\end{align}

Now, consider for $n$ dices. The probability of the all values be  $\geq 15$ is
\begin{align}
P(X_{1}\geq 15 \land X_{2}\geq 15 ... \land X_{n}\geq 15) &= \Pi_{i=1}^{n}P(X_{i}\geq 15) 
\\&= \Pi_{i=1}^{n}\left(6\times\frac{1}{20}\right) 
\\&= \left(6\times\frac{1}{20}\right)^{n}
\end{align}

The probability of there exists at least on dice with value $\geq 15$ is
\begin{align}
P(\exists i:X_{i}\geq 15) &= 1- P(\forall i:X_{i}<15) 
\\& = 1- \Pi_{i=1}^{n}P(X_{i}< 15)
\\& = 1- \Pi_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-P(X_{i}\geq 15)\right)
\\& = 1- \Pi_{i=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{6}{20}\right)
\\& = 1- \left(\frac{14}{20}\right)^{n}
\end{align}

Comment: This is the probability that **all** rolls are above $15$. OP is asking for the probability of *at least one* roll.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A_i$ denote the event "the $i$-th dice rolls $15$ or higher".

Then, what you want $P(A_1\lor A_2\lor A_3)$ but this is annoying to calculate.

It's easier to calculate $P(\neg(A_1\lor A_2\lor A_3))$ and then use the fact that $P(\neg X)=1-P(X)$.

We first write $P(\neg(A_1\lor A_2\lor A_3)) = P(\neg A_1 \land \neg A_2\land \neg A_3)$ and then use the fact that the rolls of the dice are independent, so 
$$ P(\neg(A_1\lor A_2\lor A_3)) =P(\neg A_1) \cdot P(\neg A_2) \cdot P(\neg A_3) = \left(\frac{14}{20}\right)^3$$

So the number you are looking for, the probability that at least one die rolls $15$ or higher, is $$1-\left(\frac{14}{20}\right)^3=1-0.7^3=0.657=65.7\%$$